# PHP-FPM stops responding suddenly and resumes after 2-3 minutes

Tags: nginx, php-fpm

I have 4 php-fpm servers running on backend to server Php request to Nginx. Everything works fine but sometimes suddenly PHP-FPM stops responding to Nginx and resumes well in normal mode without taking any restart after 3-5 minutes.

Any help or suggestion would be greatly appreciated to locate the issue.

Thanks

Comment: look into this 'stops' word. Try to explain it better. php-fpm pools have nice logging capabilities. Check slowlog and access.log directives and it would be nice to keep trends of status (pm.status_path) this will help you identify visually when things start looking weird and easily co-relate it with other events/trends on system which might be having issues at same time and are possibly related.

Comment: Hi , STOPS means nginx not able to communicate anymore with php-fpm on 9000 port and if i do  telnet on other ports it connects. And after few minutes it again starts communicating with php-fpm and site responds seamlessly without any restart.